# Image Comparison tuned to Human Perception

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, phash

Say I have two systems that take the same drawing commands and starts drawing on their respective platforms (i.e. HTML Canvas).  After this is done, I want to save and compare these two images to ensure that they are perceptually the same, even though the shapes and colors may be very slightly off (non-perceptible differences).

I tried using perceptual hashes, but unfortunately it does not seem sensitive enough for this task.  So for example, if you set 1000 pixels all black (for an image that is 1920x1080) on one and compare it to the other, it will be very obvious perceptually but the pHash algorithm will still return a 100% match.

I tried using nearest neighbor averaging for all pixels.  Basically, for each pixel, I averaged its value with that of a number of its neighbors and set this value back to the pixel.  This seems to work well with shapes that have hard edges and straight lines, because it only takes a very small localized change for it to be perceptibly different.  For long curves, this is not so good since there can be moderate changes throughout the entire curve with it still being considered perceptually the same.

Does there exist an algorithm that can handle perceptually small changes in many possible shapes/curves? Should I use multiple algorithms to handle this task?

Comment: Could you add some precise rules (something like "width and height of an object can be off by at most X pixels, but the aspect ratio should not change by more than Y percent", or "a pixel's colour can be off by 5%, but no 8x8 pixel region's colour should be off by more than 1%") and maybe include a few images with deviations marked acceptable or unacceptable?

Comment: what about dividing image to regions (regular grid) and store histogram of that area + some coefficients from DCT (of greyscalled cell area). That should be far better but still due to aliasing it could be sensitive to differencies near cell borders ... another way is to find points of interest and store their SIFT or SURF lists ...